# To increase the font size of label that appears on hover in chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, pie-chart

I want increase font size of label that appears on hover in chart.js,I am trying to give custom text to label but am not able to increase it's font.

```
 var myPieChart = new Chart(ctxP, {
                            type: 'pie',
                            data: {
                                labels: datas.labels,
                                datasets: [{
                                    label: 'Dataset 1',
                                    data: datas.value,
                                    backgroundColor: datas.colour
                                }],
                                others: datas.others
                            },
                            options: {
                                hover: {
                                    mode:'index'
                                },
                                legend: {
                                    display: true,
                                    position: "right",
                                    "labels": {
                                        "fontSize": 20,
                                    }
                                },
                                tooltips: {
                                    "fontSize": 20, bodyFont:20,
                                    callbacks: {                                       
                                        label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                            let label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                                            let value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                                            let otherdata = data.others[tooltipItem.index];
                                            return ' ' + label + ': ' + value + '%  ' + otherdata;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, hover: {
                                    mode: 'index',
                                    "label": {
                                        "fontSize": 20,
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })
```

i tried `hover: {                  mode: 'index', "label": { "fontSize": 20, } }` but it didn't work

[this is how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ8bL.png)

Comment: Check docs here https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the font size of tooltips in Chart.js `3.x`, just use `options.plugins.tooltip.titleFont.size` or `options.plugins.tooltip.bodyFont.size`.

```js
let ctxP=document.getElementById('mychart').getContext('2d');
let datas={
    value: [10, 15, 20, 25],
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
};
var myPieChart=new Chart(ctxP, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: datas.labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: datas.value,
            backgroundColor: datas.colour
        }],
        others: datas.others
    },
    options: {
        hover: {
            mode: 'index'
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: "right",
            "labels": {
                "fontSize": 20,
            }
        },
        tooltips: {
            // "fontSize": 20, bodyFont: 20,
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    let label=data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                    let value=data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                    let otherdata=data.others[tooltipItem.index];
                    return ' '+label+': '+value+'%  '+otherdata;
                }
            }
        },
        hover: {
            mode: 'index',
            "label": {
                "fontSize": 20,
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            tooltip: {
                titleFont: {
                    size: 20
                },
                bodyFont: {
                    size: 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="mychart"></canvas>
```

Comment: But the callback function is not working now.How do I show custom data in label?

Comment: @VikashKumarSen just use both `options.tooltips.callbacks` and `options.plugins.tooltip`.

Comment: I have but options.tooltips.callbacks isnt working.

Comment: is there a way to show custom data in the hover label without options.tooltips.callbacks?

Comment: In CHART.JS 3.x, toolitps (from version3 is now named tooltip) and legend in the chart options has been moved in plugins node. The callbacks is the simplest way to add custom data to the tooltip, but in options.plugins.tooltip.callbacks and NOT in options.tooltips.callbacks.